# jquery dialog events

Tags: jquery-ui

i'm using the dialog ui for jquery. it's works fine except that i can't seem to trigger any events, like open or close.

i the most simple version my code is this

```
$("#persoon_dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui){
        alert('test open');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        alert('test close');
    }
});
```

the dialog opens en closes but i can't even get the alert to work. i've looked at tons of examples but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Anyone an idee?

Comment: Did you *already* create the dialog before this?

Comment: Nope, the line above is $(document).ready(function(){

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax also can be helpful:

```
$("#mypopup").bind("dialogclose",function(e){
            // do  your stuff.     

 });
```

dialogopen can be used on dialog open event.